# How can I modify a function's behavior based on if it is being assigned to a variable?

Tags: c#

As in the title.

I know this is possible in other languages - is it in C#?

If the question title isn't clear, i would like something that does (something like) this:

```
MyClass exampleObject1 = new MyClass(...)

exampleObject1.sort() //sort method detects that value is not being assigned and performs sort in place.

MyClass exampleObject2 = exampleObject1.sort() //method detects assignment and returns new sorted object leaving original untouched.
```

is this something that's possible without resorting to magic? If it is possible, but in some nasty way, what is that way?

EDIT: for those wanting to see an example where you can do this (in python): [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26359217/432913). Note that i caveat it with the issue that it does not always work - but this is only in relation to the way i did it when i answered the question. Now i know more about inspect, and you can get all the information you need from the stack to work out if it is being assigned anywhere or not.

Comment: It would be cruel and unusual punishment to the user of this type to do it, even if you could, so why would you ever want to?  If you want to expose both operations, make two different methods, one `void`, one returning a new collection.

Comment: I understand that it's potentially confusing and unpleasant when the behaviour changes depending on how you call something. That's not the point. It's more a curiosity. And it's a feature i've seen in other libraries before (though i don't recall seeing it in c#), so i know it's possible sometimes. I believe it is the case in python's matplotlib for interactive plotting (and i know how to do it in python), but i don't know how to do it in c#.

Comment: @Servy - from your comment below you clearly understand what i'm asking - do you know of a way to do it?

Comment: `I know this is possible in other languages - is it in C#?` Can you give an example, please?

Comment: The *method* can never detect how its result is used -- by that time it has terminated. In C++ (not in C#) one could overload the assignment operator and create a copy there (although C++ handles and copies object values anyway, unless references are specifically declared  ...)

Comment: are you after [optional parameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx)?

Comment: Why not always sort into a new object and then simply do `exampleObject1 = exampleObject1.Sort();` - i.e. overwrite the current object?

Comment: I would strongly recommend two distinct functions, one returning something, one not. Alternatively I like AlexD's out parameter; the "no assignment" case could be signaled by passing a predefined value, if simple object creation is cheap..

Comment: Why not sort in place *and* return at the same time? Even if it returns something, there's nothing saying the calling code has to store the result in a variable. Why do you need to leave the original untouched if storing the result in a variable?

Comment: After `return` method is finished. There is no way to run some code (`finally` excluding), etc. The requirement "to see if caller assign return value to a new variable" seems like [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/299295). Why do you need that? Simply return value always. Or have 2 methods: one returning value, other is not.

Comment: @mason If you plan to use the original for other things, you'd want to store the sorted value elsewhere *so that you can still use that original*.  The primary reason to specifically return a new collection is so that *you still have the original*.  It also sends very bad signals.  When a method returns a new value, it's implying that it's not mutating the object itself.  If I call a sort method that returns a new sorted collection, I wouldn't expect it to also mutate the original.

Comment: @Servy - Exactly. I understand that it's not good practice to make things ambiguous and have behaviour depend on how things are called - but when you see `A.sort()` the assumption is always that it's in place. When you see `B = A.sort()` it's always that it's sorted a copy. I do not think this is misleading, and when it's documented appropriately it is clear IMO. Yes, it could be misleading, but i think there are cases when it is not a cruel and unusual punishment.

Comment: @will No, your solution is also sending bad signals; and even more confusingly so.  A caller will see that the method returns a value, and see that value being used in one place, and therefore assume that all uses of the method that ignore the value are wrong, and are bugs.  When they then edit the code to store the value, they could easily break the code without realizing it.  In another case someone could change the code to store the value in a non-variable location, and regardless of how you want that to function, it's almost certainly going to cause bugs for said user when it shouldn't.

Comment: @Servy I understand that. I don't *want* to do this. I thought about it in passing, and decided it's bad because of all the reasons you mention. But i still want to know if it's possible - because i am curious about anything and everything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Of course, you definitely *shouldn't* be doing this, but since the OP is more interested if it could be done for curiosity sake, then here is a snippet of code that demonstrates this capability:

```
class SomeWeirdClass
{
    private bool sortApplied = false;
    private List<int> elements;

    public IList<int> Elements
    {
        get
        {
            if(sortApplied)
            {
                elements.Sort();
                sortApplied = false;
            }

            return elements;
        }
    }

    public SomeWeirdClass(IEnumerable<int> elements)
    {
        this.elements = elements.ToList();
    }

    public SortedWeirdClass Sort()
    {
        sortApplied = true;

        return new SortedWeirdClass(this);
    }

    public class SortedWeirdClass
    {
        SomeWeirdClass parent;

        internal SortedWeirdClass(SomeWeirdClass parent)
        {
            this.parent = parent;
        }

        public static implicit operator SomeWeirdClass(SortedWeirdClass sorted)
        {
            sorted.parent.sortApplied = false;

            var elementCopy = new int[sorted.parent.elements.Count];
            sorted.parent.elements.CopyTo(elementCopy);

            var result = new SomeWeirdClass(elementCopy);
            result.Sort();

            return result;
        }
    }    
}
```

Now using it in a program:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    SomeWeirdClass original = new SomeWeirdClass(new[] { 5, 1, 4, 3, 2 });

    Console.WriteLine("Original Data: ");
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", original.Elements));

    SomeWeirdClass copy = original.Sort();

    Console.WriteLine("Original Data after Sort and Assignment: ");
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", original.Elements));

    Console.WriteLine("Sorted Copy:");
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", copy.Elements));

    original.Sort();

    Console.WriteLine("Original Data after Sort without Assignment: ");
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", original.Elements));
}
```

The program outputs:

```
Original Data:
5 1 4 3 2
Original Data after Sort and Assignment:
5 1 4 3 2
Sorted Copy:
1 2 3 4 5
Original Data after Sort without Assignment:
1 2 3 4 5
```

The hack here is that sorting actually creates a temporary class which wraps the original. Unless that result is implicitly cast to the original type via assignment, the sorting effects will be applied to the original dataset. If assignment is made, the sorting is cancelled, and a copy is made for the new variable.

Comment: Exactly the sort of hell i was after. Thanks. This is the reason i like asking questions about this sort of stuff.

Comment: of course, @will, you wont actually be using code like this, right? :P

Comment: I like to write code with an imaginary future me standing behind me with something hard and heavy.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible in a reliable way. The compiler can optimize

`MyClass exampleObject2 = exampleObject1.sort();` to `exampleObject1.sort();` if `exampleObject2` is not used.

To answer a slightly different question: you could return a `Lazy<MyClass>`. So you can do the sort only if the result is actually used.

Answer (score 0):

Split the Copy and Sort methods into two distinct methods. If I want to sort a copy, I should be responsible for copying before I sort. For example:

```
var copy = myCollection.Copy();
copy.Sort();
```

The goal should be making it clear what your function is doing to any calling code. Different behavior based on usage is only going to lead to bugs, at least in the C# world.

Comment: You cannot have two methods that differ only in return type. But I like the separation of Copy and Sort.