# Get call string for a Python function, as typed on the command line

Tags: python, read-eval-print-loop, introspection

I would like to store the exact string that was typed for a function call, from the function itself using introspection (I cannot/don't want to hack the command line interpreter -- so, for example getting history from readline or whatever is not what I am looking for).

Let's say, if user typed:

```
>>> myfunc('a', 'b', 1, mykwarg='hello')
```

I would like to get the call string (i.e. `myfunc('a', 'b', 1, mykwarg='hello')`)
from the code inside `myfunc`.

I can craft something like this:

```
def myfunc(a,b,c,mykwarg=None):
    frame = inspect.currentframe()
    sig = inspect.signature(myfunc)
    args = []
    for param in sig.parameters.values():
        if param.name in frame.f_locals:
                args.append(f"{param.name}={str(frame.f_locals[param.name])}")
    cmd = f"{frame.f_code.co_name}({','.join(args)})"

    print(cmd)
```

I get:

```
>>> myfunc('a', 'b', 1, mykwarg='hello')
myfunc(a=a,b=b,c=1,mykwarg=hello)
```

Which is not exactly what user typed. Also, I hope there is something more
robust and less 'hackish' to try...

**Use case**: I want to be able to associate a command call from my library with its result. I do not want to hard-code the command call storage for each function, I would prefer to use a decorator or something like that. This is probably much easier to do from the REPL, but I would like to not depend on it (like, if user calls the function from its own program, it should still be able to associate the command call with the result).

Comment: Look for answers about the Python REPL.

Comment: @smci thanks but I do want an answer too much related to the Python REPL (see my edit)

Comment: Also, can you help us understand why it matters whether you get the literal user input: `myfunc('a', 'b', 1, mykwarg='hello')`, or the equivalent `myfunc(a=a,b=b,c=1,mykwarg=hello)`, you can always retrofit the quotes, and strip the named argument association? What's your use-case? Are you simply playing around with the REPL, or does it actually break anything? (if so, provide an example and explain what it breaks and why) And can you give any compelling reason why not use the REPL? If not, this isn't really a real question, IMO.

Comment: I think you can use some of the stuff in my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26359952/432913) to achieve what you want.

Comment: @smci question edited to add the use case

Comment: Ok well that's ***introspection***, especially if you want to tell if each arg was passed by positional or named (kwarg) association. Does @will's answer work for your case?

Comment: @scmi, @will: well, Will's answer does not work `lines` is `None` from the interpreter.

Comment: @mguijarr can you try returning the inspect object without delving further into it and just returning the whole thing? See if there's anything useful?

Comment: I think I am going to give a try to the `dis` way... Not sure if it is a good idea, though

Answer (score 1):

Finally I answer my own question, hopefully it can help someone else one day.

I decided to try to go the `dis` way, ie. "disassembling" the Python code object of
the outer frame calling my function, to see how it has been called to be able to
reconstruct the command line:

```py
import dis
import inspect
import io
import ast
import re

def get_function_call_string():
    in_func = False
    args=[]
    kwargs=[]
    func_name = inspect.stack()[1][3]
    frame = inspect.currentframe().f_back.f_back
    dis_output = io.StringIO()
    dis.dis(frame.f_code, file=dis_output)
    for line in dis_output.getvalue().split('\n'):
        instr = re.findall(r'^.*\s([A-Z_]+)\s*', line)[0]
        if instr.startswith("CALL_FUNCTION") and in_func:
           break
        elif instr.startswith('LOAD_'):
            name = re.findall(r'^.*\s\((.+)\)$', line)[0]
            if in_func:
                if name.startswith('('):
                    kwargs = ast.literal_eval(name)
                else:
                    args.append(name)
            elif name == func_name:
                in_func = True
    kwargs = [f"{a}={args.pop()}" for a in kwargs]
    return f"{func_name}({', '.join(args)}{', ' if kwargs else ''}{', '.join(kwargs)})"
```

Example:

```
>>> def f(a,b,arg="toto"):
        print(get_function_call_string())
>>> f(1,"test","example")
f(1, 'test', 'example')
>>> f(1, "test", arg="hello")
(1, 'test', arg='hello')
```

It is not a complete answer, since it cannot handle some argument types like
dict or list... I maybe will continue on this or change my mind and do differently.